Fate of phosphatidylcholines in exosomes when triglycerides are released from adipocytes
I am not a physiologist by any stretch of the imagination, so excuse me for my potentially naive question.
My understanding is that triglycerides from long-term fat storage are released via exosomes*, whereupon they are split into fatty acids (which are subsequently catabolized during b-oxidation in the mitochondria to generate chemical energy in the form of ATP...). The exosomes are primarily made of phosphatidylcholines. What happens to the phosphatidylcholines (PCs) that form the exosomes? Are the PCs reabsorbed into cell membranes? Or, are they primarily split into their fatty acid constituents, then catabolized by B-oxidation? What is the main fate of the PCs from the exosomes?
*alternatively, are fatty acids primarily released from adipocytes using vesicles instead of exosomes?
Thanks for any insight.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to worldbuilding. Can you clarify what is the worldbuilding problem you are seeking help with? What I read here sounds like a plain and straight biology question. Our scope is described in the [help]

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a worldbuilding question. At best it belongs on either [biology.se] or [medicalsciences.se]. At worst, the OP needs to be patient and finish his/her education. It is always good medical practice to carefully read the manual before operating. In this case, that's the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask].
